# How do I search for different data types in a lightswitch editable grid?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a custom search textbox that searches for strings inside the grid. But I want the user to be able to search for dates and decimals as well from the same search textbox. Is this possible on the desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Search" functionality will only search on "strings" data types. It will NOT search on Dates or decimals, etc.
.
The best thing I could think of here would be to basically build your own Search button that is really just an input field to a Custom RIA Service, and that RIA Service would do all the "querying" you need.

Let me know if that helps or not.
THX - Matt

Comment: Thanks man, yeah I researched this for a while and couldn't find anything. Thanks for verifying my thoughts

Answer (score 1):

This will only work with List and Tile List screens not Tables..
and also only search the active pages if +- 300 records turn Page count off it still runs fast.
Add Standard Search method to the the command bar
optionally make it invisible, (I prefer that)

add this to the post render for the j20Resources table List display

myapp.BrowseResources.j20Resources_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    // Write code here.
    $(element).find("input").attr("value", contentItem.screen.j20Resources.search);
    var $element = $(element);
    var unorderedList = $($("ul", $element)[0])
    unorderedList.attr("data-filter", "true");
    unorderedList.attr("data-filter-placeholder", "search ...");
    unorderedList.on("listviewcreate", function (event, ui) {
        //we'll see if we can use this
    });
};

Search box will always show half line (cant find a way to fix that)
click in box and enter 2 or more characters to search the live dom - that means anything and see the magic.

I wish the Standard Search box could work like this.